# Una idea de como crear una matriz usando funciones

Tags: python, funciones, lista

bueno yo soy un novato y estoy aprendiendo para python y quiero saber si alguien me puede ayudar con la creacion de una matriz, es decir como podria ser el codigo si quiero una matriz con funciones, yo la he creado de esta manera facil:

```
m=[[1,2,3], 
  [4,5,6], 
  [7,8,9]]
a=""

for k in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
       # print(m[k][j])
       a+=str(m[k][j])+'\t'
print(a)
a=""
```

El hecho es que quiero una matriz hecha con funciones y que sea mas grande tipo 5x6 por decirlo, se que es mucho pedir pero si tambien hay alguna manera en que pueda eliminar un valor ya sea de la fila o la columna(No la fila ni la columna) de antemano muchas gracias por su ayuda.

...Olvide mencionarlo y es que a la hora de imprimirlo el resultado se vea literalmente en forma de matriz o mas bien sin corchetes

Comment: Alejandro deberías aclarar un poco más la pregunta ¿como se obtiene la matriz?¿se le pide al usuario preguntando el numero de filas y columnas?¿Si es así, se pide cada fila o cada elemento uno a uno? La pregunta es muy amplia, requieres crear la función y un método para imprimirla. En cuanto a eliminar un valor te refieres a dejarlo con valor  o ó nulo o eliminarlo realmente (operación no propia de un matriz ya que implica dejar una fila con una columna menos).

Answer (score -1):

Yo te recomendaria usar numpy. Te facilitará mucho las operaciones y las representaciones.

[Ejemplos de matrices con numpy en español.](http://pendientedemigracion.ucm.es/info/aocg/python/modulos_cientificos/numpy/index.html#matrices)

[Ejemplos de matrices con numpy en ingles](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html)

[Ejemplo de numpy con pandas para una representacion mas limpia.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html)

Comment: Aunque probablemente tengas razón, las respuestas solo con enlaces no son bien recibidas aqui. O bien debería ser un comentario, o bien al menos explica un poco que es numpy y como podría ayudar al OP a solucionar su problema :)